# Custom domain getting me to appID.appspot.com

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I've followed the steps to get my custom domain working with GAE. I know well all these steps and actually the following is the short and fantastic way.

> 1 - Go to appengine.google.com, open your app
>
> 2 - Administration > Versions > Add Domain... (your domain has to be linked to your Google Apps account, follow the steps to do that including the domain verification.)
>
> 3 - Go to www.google.com/a/yourdomain.com
>
> 4 - Dashboard > your app should be listed here. Click on it.
>
> 5 - myappid settings page > Web address > Add new URL
>
> 6 - Simply enter www and click Add
>
> 7 - Using your domain hosting provider's web interface, add a CNAME for www for your domain and point to ghs.googlehosted.com
>
> 8 - Now you have www.mydomain.com linked to your app.
>
> - If you want naked domain, i.e. mydomain.com, use a redirect un your DNS administrator (not in Google Apps) and point it to www.mydomain.com.

Now that I've done that all, I can go to my appengine app successfully using my custom domain. For example http://cic.mx and http://www.cic.mx both take me to my app. But URL changes to -myappid-.appspot.com and I don't want it to happen !

Has anyone solved this issue?

I'm using a php app on the appengine, with a wordpress instance.

Comment: Are you sure you used a CNAME and not a redirect?

Comment: Request to www.cic.mx responds with a HTTP 302 redirect to http://cicicalia.appspot.com/ It seems that your code is doing this, e.g. Wordpress

Comment: Sure about CNAME, take a look: http://cl.ly/image/2G1l301i200k    Could it be something at .yaml ??

Comment: I've seen what you refer, Wooble, in fact cic.mx is appropriately giving the 302 redirect to www.cic.mx but then, www.cic.mx shows also a 302 redirection to cicicalia.appspot.com; this second redirection is the one I'm trying to avoid. I've configured www.cic.mx with the CNAME pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com and there's no redirection coded anywhere...so I still don't get why we're getting this second redirection. Take a look: http://cl.ly/image/2Q0Y2q3e3t2d

Comment: Can you please post your app.yaml configuration file ?

Comment: HERE the YAML: http://cl.ly/code/0B3p03160S0w. Additionally, I tried directly wp debugging at DB UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='https://cic.mx' WHERE option_name='home' or option_name='siteurl'. It changed the routes, but it couldn't find posts, for example https://cic.mx/?p=46 was not reachable. Then used https://www.cic.mx as option_value. It didn't worked. Then I decided to test by removing secure: always at app.yaml, with no success. Do you think that making the URL change to https://www.cic.mx, using secure: always, and updating posts' URL with velvet plugin could complete the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time and a number of trials and errors including several clean installs, resulted to be an error at wp-config.php.

The one that worked was taken exactly as is at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project just with appropriate configuration for database connection.

Additionally, I've added the multisites code referred at http://frankie.bz/#wordpress-multisite-on-google-app-engine-php-beta but it takes the url substitution back again. So for now recommendation for Wordpress install at appengine with custom domain is to forget about multisites and follow:

1. **Full steps before wp-config**: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress
2. **Copy wp-config** from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project with you app-id configuration.
3. **Go to** https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~YOUR_APP_ID/appengine/settings and verify your domain.
4. Follow steps 2 and 3 therein for **naked and www** domains configuration at your DNS.
5. **Wait for propagation**.

Thanks everyone for your efforts towards finding this solution.

PD.- If I get to work multisites with custom domain, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this new custom domain settings page from Google Developers Console:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Click on your project
3. On the left click "App Engine"
4. Click "Settings"

There you can have the option to add naked / www domain directly, without Google App or redirect

Comment: I've done this. Nevertheless, for the naked domain it requires me to update A records, which I don't want to update because I still have other things in my FTP *.cic.mx. That's essentially why I have a redirect using `header("Location: http://www.cic.mx/");` just for http://cic.mx. After that www.cic.mx should be loading files at my cicicalia appengine app. See: http://cl.ly/image/2S3G1s1G1W02

Comment: @user2178032 OK, on double check it seems http://www.cic.mx/ is returning a 302 Found header, redirecting to http://cicicalia.appspot.com/

So there is noting to deal with any of the DNS settings, instead you need to check your wordpress configuration and see if there's anywhere wordpress used cicicalia.appspot.com as the default host name. You might want to tag this question as a "wordpress" issue as well.

Comment: thanks for this hint @lawrence-mok, I can think two possibilities now, perhaps a .YAML or a WP-CONFIG misconfiguration. I'll take a deeper research on this and post here any findings.

Comment: I tried directly at DB `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='https://cic.mx' WHERE option_name='home' or option_name='siteurl'`. It changed the routes, but it couldn't find posts, for example `https://cic.mx/?p=46` was not reachable. Then used `https://www.cic.mx` as `option_value`. It didn't worked. Then I decided to test by removing `secure: always` at app.yaml, with no success.  Do you think that making the URL change to `https://www.cic.mx`, using `secure: always`, and updating posts' URL with [velvet plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) could complete the job?

Comment: @chuycepeda I'm no expert in word press, the only thing obvious is you might want to check the WordPress Admin -> Settings -> General any make sure WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are set correctly.

Oh and I noticed your https error: https://cic.mx/?p=46 - Google's SSL is not yet working with naked domain, they are working on this. For now you have to use the one with www

Comment: Great to read this. I've tried several things with no success yet. In fact the direct database change I've referred is equivalent to wp url and site url changes you suggest. Last thing to try is purchasing google ssl for www subdomain and try again. I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: I've now an SSL for my Custom domain. I've updated database values to 'h t t p s : / / www.cic.mx' I've updated my wordpress contents' urls using Velvet Plugin. I can see that links are updated but contents are not found, and still when I give my custom domain to a browser, it ends redirecting to cicicalia.appspot.com... just don't know where else to go...I think this may be an open issue in GAE with wordpress.